# Simple JFileChooser FileFilter not working

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filefilter

The following is a simple code for saving a file on a user input directory using a `JFileChooser` derived from [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19806566) answer from another stackoverflow question. However, this code will not work as intended as the file filter does not display all the defined filters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame main = new JFrame();

    JButton saveto = new JButton("save");
    saveto.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        { 
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int retval = chooser.showDialog(chooser, "Save");

            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);

            if (retval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
            {
                File f_sample = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                System.out.println(f_sample + ".csv");
            }
        }
    });

    main.add(saveto);
    main.setSize(300,300);
    main.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    main.setVisible(true);
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

The file `f_sample` also will contain null but removing the filter will cause the file `f_sample` to work as intended, containing the file selected. So I assumed that the cause of the malfunction is on the `FileFilter`

What is wrong with the file filter? And how can I make it work? Note that the code is from the Oracle Tutorial with a small modification.

> Last minute modification

So I used `chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);` instead of `chooser.setFileFilter(filter);` and the file `f_sample` now contains the file defined by the user. However, the defined filters will still not show on the `JFileChooser` window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are showing your chooser before setting the filter

change to

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG & GIF Images", 
                                                                        "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int retval = chooser.showDialog(chooser, "Save");

// etc
```